# Collectors.averagingInt - is this a running average or does it keep all previous numbers in memory?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

In the following code does the averaging work as a running average or does it keep all previous integers in memory and recalculate the average every time? What I want is a running average as the number of integers in the file can be extremely large (so I don't want them all kept in memory), but another dev pointed out the fourth line might actually try to keep all integers in memory and recalculate the average every time. Which one is correct? Thanks

```
return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream()
        .flatMap(n -> Arrays.stream(n.split(" ")))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

Comment: Why should it keep all values in memory?

Answer (score 4):

An averaging collector doesn't need to keep all the numbers it is averaging in memory: all it needs to keep track of is the sum and count of the elements, which are then divided at the end to yield the average.

As such, it doesn't matter how many things are read from the file: the space used to calculate the average is constant.

---

There is an bit in *Effective Java* 3rd Edition, on page 214, which says that you should only use certain collectors as downstream collectors - `Collectors.averagingInt` is one such collector. You don't need to use these collectors as "primary" (if that's the correct term) collectors, because the same functionality is available directly on the stream's API.

The more correct way is to use `IntStream`, which has an `average()` method:

```
return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream()
        .flatMap(n -> Arrays.stream(n.split(" ")))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .average()   // Returns an OptionalDouble
        .orElse(0);  // averagingInt returns 0 if the stream is empty.
```

Comment: Cool thanks, that's what I was looking for -  it only keeps the sum and count in memory and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can rewrite this expression without using `.map` as follows:

```
return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream()
        .flatMap(n -> Arrays.stream(n.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double avg = Stream.of("10 20 30 40 50").flatMap(n -> Arrays.stream(n.split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt));
        System.out.println("Average = " + avg);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Average = 30.0
```

It calculates the average of the array of integer strings resulted from `split(" ")` and keep that in memory.